# how to prevent struts2 auto data convention from throwing exception

Tags: java, struts2, web-frameworks

I am new to Struts.I provide a model courseBean to the views to capture information.

It works perfectly if I input correct information with the correct form.
Otherwise, if I input with the wrong format, it will throw exception.

Say, I entered `abcd` in the `courseBean.startDate`, it will throw exception because `abcd` cannot be changed into `Date` format.

Is there any ways to prevent those exception? Or Should I make a new Bean Class and set all the attributes of that class to be String?

```
            <!--Title-->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Title:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="courseBean.title" placeholder="Title" value="<s:property value="courseBean.title" />"/>
                </div>
            </div>

         <!--Start Date-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Start Date:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="courseBean.startdate" placeholder="Start Date" value="<s:property value="courseBean.startdate" />" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

This questions focus on the **auto data format convention** of the input to the Bean.

Such as `WARNING: Error setting expression 'courseBean.fee' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1b40489'` when I input **""** in the textfield which map to the **courseBean.fee**

Comment: You may validate with validator interceptor before set

Comment: @muthu I hav edited my answer :) I am focusing on auto data format convention. Is the validator can prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to validate the data that the user entered in your form. This can be done in many ways, with [Annotations (section Validation Annotations)](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/annotations.html), with [XML](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/form-validation-using-xml.html) or with a simple `validate()` method in your action. You can search on the Internet lots of examples of how to validate data with Struts2 if the official documentation isn't enough.

Then I want to add something related with your jsp. Struts2 has built-in tags that render lots of things and help you to communicate the action with jsps. If we are talking about forms, we have for example `<s:form>` that can help you, for example, not to hardcode the url of the action in an HTML form or `<s:textfield>` that can be useful for render validation errors.

If the problem is that you want to use the Twitter Bootstrap notation for build your page, there is a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/) that render the HTML ready to use that CSS Framework.

**EDIT**

```
WARNING: Error setting expression 'courseBean.fee' 
with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1b40489'
```

The problem with your aproach is that you are trying to assign a `String []` to a field that probably isn't a `String []` (maybe it's a `Date`). You have to take the `String` and parse it to convert it to a `Date` object. Also, if you don't know how `<s:textfield>` and `<s:form>` work in Struts2, you should take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-stextfield-textbox-example/). It could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I have a problem with the xml form validation. I defined some actions in the same class, they share the same courseBean. Some actions is to retrieve database record but some actions is to get user input. When I request those actions retrieving database record, in that time, the courseBean has not been set. This will violate the validation. So I should refactor my design, make a class to do the actions which retrieve the database record only and to make a class to do the actions which accept the data input and validation?

Comment: Btw, the questions is focusing on the auto data format convention.

Such as `WARNING: Error setting expression 'courseBean.fee' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1b40489'`

Is that XML validation can prevent this problem?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have applied the Struts2 tag  library with plugin and the XML validation. They make my jsp much more clear than before, but I also want to prevent the deadline of the course is before today. So I should add `validate` method in the Action to do checking? Is that any problems if I use XML validation and `validate` method together??

Comment: btw, I ask other question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833456/should-i-retrieve-database-record-in-struts2-view-layer