# Should I retrieve database record in Struts2 view layer?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, struts2, struts-action

I have a edit page in which I want to retrieve the **subjects** and **levels** from database and display as select option for user to edit the **course**.

When the form is submitted, it will make a new request , the user input is captured by **courseBean** with XML validation. When the XML validation failed, it will forward with the **courseBean** which just captured the user input to the **edit.jsp**.

[image]

So every time I go the **edit.jsp**, I will retrieve the database records. Should I do it in that way?

Besides, I tried to retrieve the **subject lit** and **level lit** and store them as the request attribute in the action class which displays **edit.jsp** at the first time. But when the new request is made from the user input, the **subject list** and **level list** retrieved from the database will be no longer available.

codes (edit.jsp) :

```xml
<%
    Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session2.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session2.createQuery("from Subject");
    List subjectList = q.list();
    List levelList = session2.createQuery("from Level").list();
%>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Subject</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="subject_id">
            <%
                for (Object subjectObject : subjectList) {
                    Subject subject = (Subject) subjectObject;
            %>
            <option value="<%=subject.getId()%>"><%=subject.getName()%></option>
            <%  } //end for %>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Level</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="level_id">
            <%
                for (Object levelObject : levelList) {
                    Level level = (Level) levelObject;
            %>
            <option value="<%=level.getId()%>"><%=level.getName()%></option>
            <%  } //end for %>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can have them in your session (request.getSession().setAttribute()) until the validation is successful.

Comment: @dinukadev I think this is another way to do it;:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Struts2 you won't need to use `Scriptlet`s (`<% stuff %>`) anymore. They're old, bad, they're business logic injected in view pages, do not use them. You do not need JSTL neither, just using Struts2 tags you can achieve any result.

For a better decoupling and separation of code and concepts, you should have:

1. `DAO Layer`: it does just the plain queries;
2. `BUSINESS Layer`: it exposes the DAO Layer results through `Service`(s), aggregating multiple DAOs calls and performing several business operations when needed;
3. `PRESENTATION Layer`: The Actions, that in Struts2 acts as the Model; here you call the Service from the Business Layer, to retrieve the objects needed by the JSP;
4. `JSP (VIEW Layer)`: the JSP contains the plain HTML, and accesses the data needed through the Accessors (Getters) of the Action, and eventually any other needed element from the Value Stack (`#session`, `#request`, etc).

   In your example, all of this

> ```java
> <% 
>    Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
>    Transaction tx = session2.beginTransaction();
>    Query q = session2.createQuery("from Subject");
>    List subjectList = q.list();
>    List levelList = session2.createQuery("from Level").list(); 
> %>
> ```

should be in DAO/Business Layers, exposed by two function like `getSubjectList();` and `getLevelList();`. Then in your Action you should have something like:

```java
public class YourAction {

    private List<Object> levelList; // private
    private List<Object> subjectList; // private

    public String execute() throws Exception {      
        // Call the service, load data
        levelList = getMyService().getLevelList();
        subjectList = getMyService().getSubjectList();

        // Forwarding to the JSP
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Object> getLevelList() {
        return levelList;
    }
    public List<Object> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }

}
```

and in your JSP, instead of:

> ```xml
> <select name="subject_id">
> <%
>   for (Object subjectObject : subjectList) {
>       subject subject = (Subject) subjectObject;
> %>
>       <option value="<%=subject.getId()%>"><%=subject.getName()%></option>
> <%
>   } //end for
> %>
> </select>
> ```

you access the list like (ugly mixed HTML/Struts2 way):

```xml
<select name="subject_id">
    <s:iterator value="subjectList">
        <option value="<s:property value="id"/>">
            <s:property value="name"/>
        </option>   
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

or, in the case of a Select, with the proper Struts2 UI Select Tag:

```xml
<s:select name = "subject_id" 
          list = "subjectList" 
       listKey = "id" 
     listValue = "name" />
```

If separating all the layers is too difficult at the beginning, flatten the first three levels in the Actions, just to understand how to separata Java (Action) and Struts2 UI Tags (JSP).
 When understood, you can move the DAO logic to the business layer, preferably into an EJB. When achieved that, split again with more granularity...

The Action will be something LIKE this:

```java
public class YourAction {

    private List<Object> levelList; // private
    private List<Object> subjectList; // private

    public String execute() throws Exception {      
            Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx = session2.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session2.createQuery("from Subject");
            subjectList = q.list();
            levelList = session2.createQuery("from Level").list();

        // Forwarding to the JSP
            return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Object> getLevelList() {
        return levelList;
    }
    public List<Object> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }    
}
```

About your question on multiple loading of the lists, you can use a cache (better if with a timer) if the list is fixed (it changes one a month for example), or loading it every time, there aren't  problems in doing that.
Please note that if validation fails, the ValidationInterceptor will forward the request to the JSP mapped in the INPUT type result, without reaching the execute() method, so you should implement Preparable interface from Action and put the loading stuff into `prepare()` method, execute every time by the PrepareInterceptor

```java
public class YourAction implements Preparable {

    private List<Object> levelList; // private
    private List<Object> subjectList; // private

    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // Call the service, load data, 
        // every time even if validation fails
        levelList = getMyService().getLevelList();
        subjectList = getMyService().getSubjectList();
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {      

        // Forwarding to the JSP
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Object> getLevelList() {
        return levelList;
    }
    public List<Object> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }
}
```

Proceed by steps, the framework is easy and powerful, the web has plenty of examples and StackOverflow provides some great support...

Comment: Thank you so much, it is best answer I have even seen. I have used your approach and the jsp looks better than before.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a cache. But if the database records are bound to change frequently it's inadvisable.

If however the Query in question is small (I think it is) querying the database shouldn't be a big performance problem.

On another note, looking at your JSP all I see is deprecated and misuse of JSP scriplets.

Since you have added the tag struts 2 I will assume that this is a struts 2 web project. Consider (strongly) using built in struts ui tags for the work done in you scriplets.

Your approach can only be described as using a bunch of dynamos to power a city when you have a nuclear reactor at your disposal.

I suggest you start here : http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/home.html

This will give you a proper idea of the framework and it's full capabilities.

Comment: @Thihata do u mean the select tag for structs?  but how can I access the variable define in jsp scriplet

Comment: You don't define it in the scriplet. JSP is the view. At the very least you should use the struts 2 action classes to get this done. And I stress that it's the very least and not a very good practice.

Comment: Do u mean setting the property of action class?  and use struct2 select tag for that property?

Comment: Yes Ideally though you should have isolated your business logic in separate classes. And data access in another layer. But if the application is relatively small with no evolution potential compromises can be made.

Answer (score 1):

One advice, if you want to stick to MVC architecture then never have Business Logic in View. According to MVC architecture the UI Engineers who work with View need not not to know about the Business Logic at all.

Intermixing HTML and Java Code in your JSP page complicates the View and will cause problems in maintaining the code.

Make use of [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-crud-example-1.html) tutorial to see how to implement CRUD operations in Struts 2.

Comment: how about I use tag library to separate the Java code and HTML?