# How to match the password in database and user defined password in Struts2?

Tags: java, jdbc, authentication, struts2

Struts Code:

```
action name="alreadylogin" class="struts.alreadylogin"

            result name="success">/indexlogin.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/failure.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>            
        </action>
```

Java Class Code:

```
public String loginemail;

    String loginpassword;

    public String execute()  {


try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/hr@localhost:1521:XE");

            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from  logininfo");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String lemail = rs.getString(3);
                String lpassword = rs.getString(4);



            if(lemail.equals(loginemail)&&(lpassword.equals(loginpassword)))

                return "success";

            }
}

            catch(SQLException s)
            {
                return "error";
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
            {
                return "error";
            }
```

It shows the error to Insert Finally into the code or return a String. If I use finally, the return statement will execute no matter what which destroys the purpose of checking for a user to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If this test is not passed, no result String is returned.

```
if(lemail.equals(loginemail)&&(lpassword.equals(loginpassword)))
    return "success";
}
```

Simply add

```
  else {
    return "input";
}
```

BTW you should never query for `*`, nor [performing queries from the action itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837913/1654265).

And most even important, **instead of querying ALL the fields of ALL the records from the database, traversing them in JAVA, try using the `WHERE` keyword** :|

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block executed before `return` statement which any block should return in your case. The error is that you should return a string from the method `execute` regardless of implementation is used. If you are using `try/catch` blocks and if you place `return` in both blocks then you don't need a `finally` block to return a value from a method nor the `return` statement at the end of the method. Because if you try to place a `return` statement there you should get `Unreachable code error`, and there's no such error if you forgot to return from the code above.