# s:property not shown value Struts2

Tags: java, properties, struts2

I have the following:

```
select name="nroPartido" style="color:#F5FFFA; background-color: #CC9900; font-weight: bold;">
<%
        //se crean las listas
        java.util.ArrayList<Partido> lista = Pronosticos.getInstance().getMiLista();
                int nro = 0;
        for (Partido p : lista) {              
                out.println("<option value=\"" + nro + "\">" + p.getLocal() +"-" +p.getVisitante() + "</option>");
                nro++;
        }
%>
</select>
```

So when I click the button the value of nro will be the value of the var nroPartido that is in the pronosticoAction class:

```
package acciones;


import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class pronosticoAction extends ActionSupport {

    private int nroPartido;


    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(nroPartido);
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public int getNroPartido() {
        return nroPartido;
    }


    public void setNroPartido(int nroPartido) {
        this.nroPartido = nroPartido;
    }






}
```

Then what i want to do is print that number in a JSP page. So i do the following:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Detalles partido</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Chosen number</h1>

<h4>
    You select number: <s:property value="nroPartido" />
</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it only shows this:

[image]

If someone could help me will be very useful
Thanks!

Comment: For a start this: `<s:property value="nroPartido"></<s:property>` should look like this `<s:property value="nroPartido"/>`

Comment: Just a typo in the code.

Comment: Yes I changed that to <s:property value="nroPartido" /> but stills don't appear the number :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is wrong, both syntactically and conceptually:

```
<s:property value="nroPartido"></<s:property>
```

there is an extra `<` , and the `<s:property/>` tag should self-closed, like a void element in XHTML:

```
<s:property value="nroPartido" />
```

That said, you should consider building your Select without using scritplets at all, by either iterating the options with `<s:iterator>`, or by using `<s:select/>` that is often the right way. You can find an example on how to do it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837913/1654265).

## EDIT

You also forgot to include the [taglib directive for Struts2 tags](http://struts.apache.org/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

> To use the Struts 2 tags on the view page, you must include a tag library directive. Typically, the taglib directive is `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`. So the prefix for all the Struts 2 tags will be "s".
> If you want to actually read the Struts 2 tag TLD file, you'll find it in the META-INF folder of the Struts 2 core jar.

Comment: Hi @AndreaLigios thanks for answering. I made that change and it doesn't appear the number. I edit my code with your correction.

Comment: Yes you are right! I use it in other JSP but in this I didn't put it. Thanks for your help